# Protractor CSV file upload doesn't work

Tags: protractor

I have problem when trying to upload a csv of excel files via protractor. File is valid. When I upload it manually everything is fine. But for some reason, upload with protractor says that size is 0, and type is not recognized.

[Screenshot of file details after upload](http://puu.sh/lr95M/fbe34a6c72.png)

Upload code:

```
var fileToUpload = './test.csv';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

element(by.css("input[type=\"file\"]")).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Also I have tried with absolute path, without path.resolve, and also I have tried with xlsx file. Problem remains the same.

Comment: I don't know protractor, but a sample of your CSV file would be nice. CSV files are simple and easy on first sight, but they have their traps.

Comment: How do you upload the file using protractor? Show some code please.

Comment: I have added code, and regarding sample of csv file, as I already said, file is ok, when uploaded from UI, manually, works fine.

Comment: where do you have the file? Could you outline your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the cause. From my tests it seems like the File `type` is missing, see below:

For a `.csv` file:

```
File
    lastModified: 1468589472000
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 15 2016 14:31:12 GMT+0100 (BST)
    name: "valid-import.csv"
    size: 198
    type: ""
    webkitRelativePath: ""
```

For a `.svg` file:

```
File
    lastModified: 1468587182000
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 15 2016 13:53:02 GMT+0100 (BST)
    name: "valid-import.svg"
    size: 1030
    type: "image/svg+xml"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Note the missing type attribute — I'm trying to dig further into this, if I find anything I'll update this answer.